# Seaborn's heatmap when annot=True displays 0, instead of 0.0. How do I change this?

Tags: python, numpy, seaborn, rounding, heatmap

I am building a seaborn heatmap in Python. The values will be shown in the heatmap figure (`annot=True`). I round all the values on the matrix (a pandas DataFrame) that will be represented on the heatmap to 1 decimal place using `np.around(matrix,1)`. Some values on the matrix are 0, then it's not a surprise numpy simply rounds then to `0` instead of `0.0`. The problem is that I need the zeros to show like `0.0` on the seaborn heatmap. Any suggestions?

Edit: I tried setting the matrix as an np array and setting up `np.set_printoptions(1,floatmode='fixed')`, but when I do this, I lose the columns labels, and I need then to build the heatmap, so this is not an option.

Edit 2: I tried changing `annot=True` to `annot=np.around(np.array(matrix),1).astype(str)`, that is, instead of showing the pd DataFrame on the heatmap, giving the matrix to be displayed transformed to a np array, rounded and "fixed" as strings, but then I get the `ValueError: Unknown format code 'g' for object of type 'str'`, which seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to round your data before hand all you need to do is change the annotation formatting. For 1 d.p you do as follows,

```
sns.heatmap(df, annot=True,fmt='.1f')
```